# Aspose Words: get warnings for every document appended

Tags: c#, aspose.words

I need to see all warnings about my generated documents.
I have a "main document" (docx) and later I append other documents (docx) to the "main document", in this way:

```cs
Aspose.Words.Document mainDoc = GenerateDocument("main.docx", myModel);
mainDoc.AppendDocument(GenerateDocument("attach1.docx", myModel), ImportFormatMode.KeepSourceFormatting);
mainDoc.AppendDocument(GenerateDocument("attach2.docx", myModel), ImportFormatMode.KeepSourceFormatting);
```

Into `GenerateDocument` method I create the `Document` object and set the `WarningCallback` in this way:

```cs
// e.g. fileName = "main.docx"
document.WarningCallback = new MyWarningCallback(fileName); 

[...]

public class MyWarningCallback : IWarningCallback {

    private string _fileName;

    public MyWarningCallback(string fileName)
    {
        _fileName = fileName;
    }

    public void Warning(WarningInfo info)
    {
        myLog.Log(LogLevel.Warn, $"{_fileName}: {info.Description}");
    }
}
```

When I convert the `mainDoc` to PDF I see correctly all warnings but all warnings refer to "mainDoc.docx"; none of the warnings refer the other attaches.

Is there a way to see the name of the appended document into the warnings?

Comment: Please create a simplified standalone console application (source code without compilation errors) that helps us to reproduce your problem on our end, ZIP and upload it (along with test documents) to Dropbox and share the download link here for testing. We will then investigate the issue on our end and provide you more information. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: @Awais no, that is not how Stack Overflow works. If you want the OP to contact your support, then do so. On this site, all code necessary to reproduce the issue must be present in the question.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to see the name of the appended documents. Document.AppendDocument method simply copies content of the source document into the destination one, so the content becomes a part of the main document.

As a possible solution you can convert each document separately to PDF and check for warnings, then concatenate PDFs using Aspose.PDF, for example.